# How to apply date range to a aggregation query using Nest client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest client to build an Aggregation query and able to get the results from the elasticsearch.

I have tried to add the date range to the query as follows. BUt while adding date range, Nest call becomes invalid.
Any suggestion that how to do add date range

``

```
var t = client.Search<USJob>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
     .Bool(b => b
     .Filter(f => f
      .Terms(t => t
     .Field("RuleID")
      .Terms(aggField)
       ), f => f
       .Range(dr => dr
        .Field(f => f.jobdate)
        .GreaterThanOrEquals(20200801)
                )
            )
        )
 )
```

``

Answer (score 0):

Try using the example code:

```
            var query = new QueryContainerDescriptor<USJob>()
            .Bool(b => b.Filter(f => f.DateRange(dt => dt
                                       .Field(field => field.jobdate)
                                       .GreaterThanOrEquals(birthdate)
                                       .LessThanOrEquals(birthdate)
                                       .TimeZone("+00:00"))));
```

It is very important to use TimeZone and limit LessThanOrEquals to not return all your index data.

And separate your queries by QueryContainerDescriptor, that way it's easy to find any inconsistencies.

References: https://github.com/hgmauri/elasticsearch-with-nest/blob/master/src/Sample.Elasticsearch.Domain/Applications/ActorsApplication.cs